# How to train a Masked Language Model with a big text corpus(200GB) using PyTorch？

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, pytorch-dataloader

Recently I am training a masked language model with a big text corpus(200GB) using [transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/). The training data is too big to fit into computer equiped with 512GB memory and V100(32GB)*8. Is it possible to find a elegant way to train model with big data?

Now I split entire training data into 20 pieces and create 20 `DataLoader`s, each dataloader loads corresponding data into memory and uses `DistributedDataParallel` to train the model. The code is below.

```py
def get_dataloader(rank, world_size, tokenizer, part_of_data, args):
    train_data_df = get_DataFrame(args, part_of_data)
    train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_data_df, tokenizer, args.max_len)

    data_collator = transformers.DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
        tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=True, mlm_probability=0.15
    )

    train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
        train_dataset,
        num_replicas=world_size,
        rank=rank,
    )

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset=train_dataset,
        batch_size=args.batch_size,
        shuffle=False,            
        num_workers=2,
        pin_memory=True,
        collate_fn=data_collator,
        sampler=train_sampler)

    return train_loader
```

By reading PyTorch Doc I find a dataloader called [IterableDataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.IterableDataset), maybe IterableDataset is more suitable for my task, but there is a NOTE in the Doc said **neither sampler nor batch_sampler is compatible with iterable-style datasets, since such datasets have no notion of a key or an index.**

So I wonder if it is possible to use `IterableDataset`, `DistributedSampler` and `DistributedDataParallel` to train model, or other elegant method to train model instead of splitting data. Thanks a lot.